# Entropy inequality for random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, entropy

How can I prove that $E(\log f_\xi (\xi)) \geq E(\log f_\eta (\xi))$?

I can only say that by linearity and logarithm property $E(\log f_\xi(\xi)) - E(\log f_\eta(\xi)) = E(\log f_\xi(\xi) - \log f_\eta(\xi)) = E(\log\frac{f_\xi(\xi)}{f_\eta(\xi)})$. But why is it greater or equal to zero?

Comment: This is called  Gibb's inequality. Article on Wikipedia has proof for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for fast and helpful answer.